# What is the difference between NSUserDefaultsController and NSArrayController?

Tags: objective-c, binding, xcode5, nsarraycontroller

I have happily used a "Array Controller" object in the interface builder. The binding worked like charm and everything works like magic.

Because of that I took a look at the "User Default Controller" - thinking that it will work similarly as the "Array Controller". To my surprise there is not binding interface in Xcode. I had to bind the UI element with the user defaults by code. Example bellow:

```
    [_cbPlaySound bind:@"value"
          toObject:[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController]
       withKeyPath:@"values.playSound"
           options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
            forKey:@"NSContinuouslyUpdatesValue"]];
```

Everything again works like it should. But why can't i bind the "User Default Controller" like the "Array Controller"?

To be clear: I did red the Apple documentation, but I still don't understand why to things that seams to me that should work similarly, they don't.

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post a more detailed code snippet? What is _cbPlaySound? If this is a button or something like that, you can go to the Interface Builder and Navigate to the Bindings Inspector (second to last icon) where you have a lot of options (Action Invocation, Availability, ...) you can bind to the `SharedUserDefaultsController` there.

Back to your question: I think the difference between those two is that `NSUserDefaultsController` is a Singleton while `NSArrayController` is not. That means you only have one instance of the UserDefaultsController in the whole app and you only get a pointer to that instance. If you use a `NSArrayController` you create your own instance which must be then made public in the Interface Builder.

So you don't really 'own' the `UserDefaultsController` and you don't need to add it specifically as an object to the Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you Tony, this the information that i was missing. Now it makes sense. Thank you again.

About "_cbPlaySound" it is a check box.